# Batch Saving Data Sets - Illustrator Error on Data Set Change

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, data-merge

I am trying to update all the Data Sets in my Illustrator document so that when I do a Batch Action Save I don't get the following error:

> The current values have not been captured and will be discarded upon switching data sets. Proceed?

[I found this StackExchange answer here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/81038/illustrator-error-on-switching-variables-data-sets), but this script is not working on my Illustrator when I execute it from the File > Script > Other Scripts menu.

Here is the code:

```
function cycleUpdateAllDatasets(doc){
for(var i = 0; i < doc.dataSets.length; i++){
var d = doc.dataSets[i];
d.display();
d.update();
 };
};
```

I am not very familiar with javasript so I am not sure why the script isn't working and was hoping someone could shed some light on this?

I am on the Adobe Illustrator CC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete code is:

```
#target illustrator
function test () {
  var doc = app.activeDocument;
  function cycleUpdateAllDatasets (doc) {
    for (var i = 0; i < doc.dataSets.length; i++) {
      var d = doc.dataSets[i];
      d.display();
      d.update();
    };
  };
  cycleUpdateAllDatasets(doc);
}
test();
```

Comment: This was it! I am glad I managed to get you! :) I couldn't respond to the original post so I had to make a new question which I know is frowned upon in this community.

Thank you!!

Comment: This is a-ok with me. I'm interested in how you use the variable data, it's quite a fun thing..