# Does the isIsolated property have something to do with the isolation mode in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

As a follow up to [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/96570/5795), I was able to select the innermost group via a script on Illustrator, but I'd like to enable the isolation mode for that group too. So that I don't have to double-ckick on all the hierarchy of parent groups to get to the one I want to "isolate".

In the the [Adobe Illustrator CC 2017 Reference (JavaScript)](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html) they mention the property `isIsolated` but I can't enable the isolation mode by setting the property to true.

What is the `isIsolated` property supposed to do?

Can it be used to enable the isolation mode for some particular group?

This is the script to make the parent group isolated.

```
if ( app.documents.length > 0 ) {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;

    if ( typeof doc.selection[0] !== 'undefined') {
        var parent = doc.selection[0].parent;

        if ( parent !== doc.selection[0] && typeof parent.layer !== 'undefined') {
            parent.isIsolated = true;
            alert(parent.isIsolated)
            //doc.selection = parent;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the doc you linked it should work on layers, groups, etc. Can you add the code you're using to the question?

Comment: @Luciano added a snippet of code, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Generally having a name like `is*` means that the attribute is meant for checking. So `isIsolated` would generally be called just `isolated` if it were meant to be used in a read and write context, like `hidden`, `locked`  `selected`.

This is pretty simple to test though, far simpler and faster than to ask random strangers on interweb. So open *ExtendScript Toolkit*, and *Illustrator*. Create a new document in illustrator and populate it with a few objects. Then type following in ExtendScript toolkit:

```
#target illustrator

var obj = app.activeDocument.pathItems[0];
alert(obj.name + "\nIsolated: " + obj.isIsolated);
obj.isIsolated = true;
```

And asa result i can say: No, isIsolated does not do much anything. In fact it does not even seem to indicate object is in isolation mode.

Comment: I made a similar test to yours, also searched the web for someone having a similar issue or some snippet of code handling isolated mode from a script, but couldn't find anything. By the way, do you know of a way to perform a double-click on the current selection from a script?

Comment: You might be able to execute the command i had this all set up for testing but then i had to go and lasercut piece of acryllic.