# How can I make a shortcut for 100% view in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shortcuts

Illustrator (and many other programs too) have a shortcut for resizing to fit/default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>

My artboard is smaller than the space of fill in my screen, I'm wondering if there's a way to have a shortcut to view at **100%** and other zoom amounts which I can choose later on.

I tried creating a new View (**View → New View**) and then applying a custom keyboard shortcut, but that seems to be *per-document*, I'm looking for a way to do this that will always work across all projects that I open.

Comment: I don't have Illustrator to test, but Photoshop uses Ctrl/1 for 100% [Cmd/1 on Mac] It also has [undefined keys by default] menu commands for 200% & Print Size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> is the shortcut for a 100% zoom.

Go to **View → Actual Size**

[image]

---

If you want to input a custom zoom level after pressing a shortcut, you need to use a script.

```
var zoomLevel = prompt("Percentage:", "100");

if ( zoomLevel ) {
    zoomLevel = zoomLevel / 100;
    app.executeMenuCommand("fitin"); // Centers the artboard to the window
    app.activeDocument.activeView.zoom = zoomLevel;
}
```

[image]

If you want to define a shortcut to launch this script, you need to use third-party apps to tell Illustrator to open the script file when a shortcut is pressed.

There are many ways to do it. In [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63439/how-to-set-keyboard-shortcut-to-run-script-in-illustrator/63446#63446), I list 3 different ones. A way to do it in windows is at the bottom of the answer.

---

There is also the `Window > Navigator` but you can't set a shortcut to focus on that input.

---

Someone in that [other question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/100357/2332) says Illustrator now (CC 2018) remembers it if you record an Action that opens a script, which would allow you to then set a shortcut for the action. This has been a problem in the past because AI would just drop out the script recording after a while. I guess on restart (maybe). I forgot.

---

---

I'll throw this in too, since I happened to make it. This code zooms all documents.

```
var aDoc = app.activeDocument;
var zoomLevel = prompt("Percentage:", "100");

if ( zoomLevel ) {

    zoomLevel = zoomLevel / 100;

    for ( var i = app.documents.length; i--; ) {

        var activeDoc = app.documents[ i ];

        // "fitin" = Fit artboard in window
        // "fitall" = Fit all artboards in window
        // "actualsize" = Actual size (100% Zoom) 
        app.executeMenuCommand("fitin");
        activeDoc.activeView.zoom = zoomLevel;

    }

    app.activeDocument = aDoc;

}
```

Comment: Illustrator (CS6) doesn't have actions that can remember a script - to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @WELZ, I didn't want to repeat the answer, but [it does mention CC 2018](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/100357/2332)

Comment: Not the same approach, but... on a per-document basis for custom Zoom, AND pan AND layer states - you can save a View. View>New View, name it, and it then shows up in your list of available views. Not easily short-keyable, but one-click get to able. I use this most often in multiple art boards...

Comment: @GerardFalla I would've liked to use that method, but they can only go per-document - which won't help much.

Comment: @WELZ - if most of your files ***tend*** to be similar, you *could* create yourself a new template files with your predefined Views, and then work from that starting point...

Comment: I tried using the script and got [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXgjg.png).

Comment: My bad, @WELZ, some code had fallen off at some point... Updated the answer.